# keep in array only items in another, different sized array - without loops

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have:

```
e = np.array([1,2,-4])
f = np.array([1,3,1,45,-2,-5,-4,3,3,3,2,-4])
```

And I want to get a new array that contains only the elemnts in f that also appear in e:

```
result = np.array([1,1,-4,2,-4])
```

what is a non - loops way to do it ?

thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.isin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
>>> f[np.isin(f,e)]
array([ 1,  1, -4,  2, -4])
```